# Как перекинуть спарсенную через jsoup информацию в первый поток из второго

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, парсер, jsoup

Вот код Activity, пока сделал Main для теста. Проблема в том, что я сделал второй поток и в нем спарсил страницу и выцепил нужные куски. Проблема в том, что я теперь не могу обновить ТекстВьювы из второго потока. Если выполнять парсинг из первого потока, то тогда неминуемый краш.

```
package ru.ursna.trulate;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String url = "https://tl.rulate.ru/book/29738/637191/ready";
    private Document doc;
    private Thread SecondThread;
    private Runnable runnable;
    TextView Title = findViewById(R.id.Title);
    TextView TextContent = findViewById(R.id.Title);
    String TextTitle = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    load();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        SecondThread = new Thread(runnable);
        SecondThread.start();
    }

    private void load() throws IOException {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    }

    private void content() {
        final String TextTitle = doc.title();
        final Elements Text = doc.select("div.content-text");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для извещения главного потока о результатах работы используйте механизм [обработчиков](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) (handlers).

Он позволяет передавать сообщения и/или Runable в очередь сообщений потока.

```
public class MainActivity extends ... {

    // предполагаем, что load выполняется в отдельном потоке
    private void load() throws IOException {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        // Делаем все что нужно и получаем результат
        MyResult result = ...

        // Runnable переданный в post будет выполнен в главном потоке
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // тут обновляем UI используя result т.д.
            } 
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: то есть я могу получить 2 строчки и через run передать их в текствьювы?

Comment: Сунул смену текста в run и в итоге тот же краш

Comment: Значит есть еще какая-то проблема. Дополните вопрос и добавьте код , который вызывает проблему и стектрейс.